# How may I change the title and the size of an acf and pacf diagram in R in a for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to plot 10 acf and pacf data of column vectors of a dataframe in r using the following code.

```
for (i in 1:10)
{
  acf(data1[,i], 108, xlim=c(4,97), ylim=c(-.4,1), main=("The Country is", i))
  pacf(data1[,i],108, xlim=c(4,97), ylim=c(-.4,1))
}
```

However, this is not working, I am getting

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:5:74: unexpected ','
4: {
5:   acf(data1[,i], 108, xlim=c(4,97), ylim=c(-.4,1), main=("The Country is",
                                                                            ^
Traceback:
```

Moreover, if I changed the ,i in main it works but I do not like the dimension. May I change it too?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, Zheyuan Li you help me a lot I just made some minor adjustments.

```
for (i in 1:10)
{
    par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
    #acf(data1[,i], ylim=c(-0.2, 1), main = paste("The Country is", r[i+1]))
    acf(data1[,i], ylim=c(-0.2, 1),main =NA)
    pacf(data1[,i], ylim=c(-0.2, 1),main =NA)
    par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
    title(r[i+1], outer=TRUE)
}
```

This would do the job